# I want to increase the performance of a SQL view which have multiple joins and case statements

Tags: sql-server, sqlperformance

In my view I have multiple joins and one of the join is on many to many relation. So when I join this table the number of records increases drastically and to resolve it i have used case statement which helps in filtering the unwanted records. But this whole filtering of unwanted records is creating the query very slow.

Here is the basic structure of my query.

```
> WITH PeriodCTE   AS (     SELECT PeriodId,            StartTime,          Name,
>           LEAD(StartTime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY TimePeriodId) [EndTime]   FROM
> Period WHERE Active = 1 )
> 
> Select * From (Select 
>         Id, 
>         Name, 
>         Period,
>         CASE      WHEN CAST(B.OpenTimestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '00:00:00.0000000'           
>                            AND (SELECT MIN(P.Starttime) FROM Period P 
>                            INNER JOIN DepartmentPeriod DP ON P.PeriodId = DP.PeriodId 
>                            WHERE DepartmentId = B.DepartmentId) 
>                               AND CTE.StartTime = (SELECT MAX(T.Starttime) FROM 
>                                                      Period P 
>                                                    INNER JOIN 
>                                                      DepartmentPeriod DP ON 
>                                                      P.PeriodId = DP.PeriodId 
>                                                    WHERE DepartmentId = B.DepartmentId) 
>                   Then 1
>                   When CAST(B.OpenTimestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN CTE.StartTime 
>                       AND '23:59:59.9999999' AND CTE.StartTime = 
>                            (SELECT MAX(P.Starttime) FROM Period P 
>                                 INNER JOIN DepartmentPeriod DP ON 
>                                 P.TimePeriodId = DP.TimePeriodId 
>                             WHERE DepartmentId = C.DepartmentId) 
>                   Then 1
>                   WHEN CAST(B.OpenTimestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN CTE.StartTime AND CTE.EndTime 
>                   THEN 1
>                   WHEN DP.DepartmentId NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT(DepartmentId) FROM DepartmentPeriod) 
>                   THEN 1
>                   WHEN CTE.StartTime IS NULL
>                   THEN 1          
>          END AS [Flag] 
>          From Bill AS B 
>          LEFT OUTER JOIN Department AS D ON B.DepartmentId = D.DepartmentId 
>          LEFT OUTER JOIN DepartmentPeriod AS DP ON D.DepartmentId = D.DepartmentId 
>          LEFT OUTER JOIN PeriodCTE AS CTE ON P.PeriodId = DP.PeriodId ) AS X 
> Where Flag = 1
```

Are there any suggestions to improve the performance of my query.

Comment: *"I can't post my query or execution plan as its a client project."* so what *are* you expecting from us here? Would you expect a mechanical to be able to tell you how to fix your car, if all you told him was "it's running slowly" and withheld basic information like the make and model, and a description of *why* it's running slow?

Comment: With only those details provided.... throw hardware at it

Comment: Tbh, I'd performance tune the query first, @uberbloke , and throw hardware at it later. Make sure it's SARGable. I *hope* the OP isn't using `CASE` expressions in the `WHERE` too. Of course, utterly impossible for us to know.

Comment: First you need to determine what you want. If you want a specific method, point it out.

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to achieve with `CASE` statement? Bottleneck is most likely there and it also looks like there is some redundancy in your implementation.

Comment: Table and Index definitions would be very helpful here. Specifically, what are the datatypes of B.OpenTimestamp and P.StartTime?

Comment: You have `AND CTE.StartTime = (SELECT MAX(T.Starttime) FROM` on line 13, but there is no table alias name `T` in your query.  What should this be?

Comment: Also you have both `PeriodID` and `TimePeriodID` in the Period table, are they supposed to be the same column?

Comment: So I went through it, and between the transcription errors (mistakes made when you tried to change the names for confidentiality reasons) and not knowing what the relationships between the tables are, there's really not much that we can do with this right now.  If you can fix the mistakes, and also give us table definitions and their relationships (ie., cardinality and uniqueness/existence) then we could do something.

Comment: Another option might be to 1) copy all of these tables over to an empty database, 2) change the table and column names for confidentiality, 3) copy your query over and change the names to match your new table/column names, 4) run Statistics on the new database. And finally, 5) run your query and capture the execution plan.  Then you can post that sanitized execution plan here, which would answer most of our questions.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that your query, as-is, will always return `1` for qualifying rows no matter what. As-is, you could change the code to read `[flag] = 1`. That said, I'll just ignore this for now.

Next,it's good to have your code formatted in an organized fashion. Not just for easier debugging and maintenance, but for better answers if you post the code on these forums. I cleaned it up to better explain my answer and to help others provide better answers:

```
WITH PeriodCTE AS 
(
  SELECT -- 1. You want an index to handle the sort for TimePeriodId
    PeriodId, StartTime, Name, LEAD(StartTime, 1) OVER (ORDER BY TimePeriodId) AS [EndTime]
  FROM  [Period]
  WHERE Active = 1
) -- INDEX: CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <name> ON [Period](TimePeriodId) WHERE Active = 1;
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    Id, 
    Name, 
    Period,
    [Flag] =
      CASE 
        WHEN CAST(B.OpenTimestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN '00:00:00.0000000' AND (
                  SELECT MIN(P.Starttime)
                  FROM   Period           AS P 
                  JOIN   DepartmentPeriod AS DP
                    ON   P.PeriodId = DP.PeriodId 
                  WHERE  DepartmentId = B.DepartmentId)
          AND CTE.StartTime = (
                  SELECT MAX(T.Starttime)
                  FROM   Period           AS P 
                  JOIN   DepartmentPeriod AS DP
                  ON     P.PeriodId = DP.PeriodId 
                  WHERE  DepartmentId = B.DepartmentId)
        THEN 1
        WHEN CAST(B.OpenTimestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN CTE.StartTime AND '23:59:59.9999999'
          AND CTE.StartTime = (
                  SELECT MAX(P.Starttime)
                  FROM   Period           AS P 
                  JOIN   DepartmentPeriod AS DP
                    ON   P.TimePeriodId = DP.TimePeriodId 
                  WHERE DepartmentId = C.DepartmentId)
        THEN 1
        WHEN CAST(B.OpenTimestamp AS TIME) BETWEEN CTE.StartTime AND CTE.EndTime
        THEN 1
        WHEN DP.DepartmentId NOT IN (SELECT /*DISTINCT*/DepartmentId FROM DepartmentPeriod) -- 2. You don't need DISTINCT Here, it causes a needless sort
        THEN 1
        WHEN CTE.StartTime IS NULL
        THEN 1
      END
  FROM      Bill             AS B
  LEFT JOIN Department       AS D   ON B.DepartmentId = D.DepartmentId 
  LEFT JOIN DepartmentPeriod AS DP  ON D.DepartmentId = D.DepartmentId 
  LEFT JOIN PeriodCTE        AS CTE ON P.PeriodId = DP.PeriodId
) AS x
WHERE Flag = 1;
```

Without DDL or an execution plan it's hard to help but here's some low-hanging fruit changes. For your first CTE against [Period] you want an index to support that query:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <name> ON [Period](TimePeriodId, StartTime)
INCLUDE (PeriodId, Name)
WHERE Active = 1;
```

Or...

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX <name> ON [Period](TimePeriodId)
INCLUDE (PeriodId, StartTime, Name)
WHERE Active = 1;
```

Next, you can lose the DISTINCT in this subquery:

```
WHEN DP.DepartmentId NOT IN (SELECT /*DISTINCT*/DepartmentId FROM DepartmentPeriod)
```

This does not change the answer but leavibg the DISTINCT the might cause the optimizer to needlessly sort those rows.

Finally - you have THREE [correlated subqueries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), also known as a [triangle join](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-triangular-joins). THIS IS WHAT IS MOST LIKELY **CRUSHING** YOUR PERFORMANCE. There are many ways you can refactor that code but it can be complicated. A simple way to improve the performance of these correlated subqueries would be to turn that correlated subquery into an indexed view if possible. The view logic would look like this:

```
CREATE {viewname} WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
SELECT {Unique key or composite key}, P.Starttime
FROM   dbo.[Period]         AS P 
JOIN   dbo.DepartmentPeriod AS DP
  ON   P.PeriodId   = DP.PeriodId
WHERE  DepartmentId = B.DepartmentId;
```

The index would be a some unique combination of values:

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX {indexname} ON {yourview}(Starttime, {unique key(s)});
```

Then, in your query you find the three places where this code exists:

```
SELECT MIN(V.Starttime)
FROM   dbo.[Period]         AS P 
JOIN   dbo.DepartmentPeriod AS DP
  ON   P.PeriodId   = DP.PeriodId
WHERE  DepartmentId = B.DepartmentId
```

and change it to...

```
SELECT MIN(V.Starttime)
FROM   {your new indexed view}
```